# Page Slant Dividers

Tags: html, css

I have manage to do the slant edge form right to left like so: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/637mr/1/), All i am trying to do now is reverse it, so for example where this one goes big on the left to small on the right i need it to go big on the right to small on the left. Basically the opposite of what i have currently.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <section class="color"></section>
            <section class="col-3 ss-style-doublediagonal"></section>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* we don't want the pseudo-elements sticking out */
}

section {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10em 10%;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.color {
    background: red;
}

/*** Individual section styles and separators ***/

/* Common style for pseudo-elements */
section::before,
section::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
}


/* Double Diagonal line */

.ss-style-doublediagonal {
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 6em;
    background: yellow;
}

.ss-style-doublediagonal::before,
.ss-style-doublediagonal::after {
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.ss-style-doublediagonal::before {
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
    transform-origin: 3% 0;
}
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to tell you what I actually changed.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/637mr/8/)

```
transform: rotate(2deg); /* was -2deg, rotating the other way now */
transform-origin: 100% 0; /* was 0 0, rotating from the other side */
```

and:

```
transform: rotate(3deg); /* was -3deg, rotating the other way */
transform-origin: 97% 0; /* was 3% 0, rotating from the other side */
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/637mr/7/)

I hope I helped you

```
  *,
    *:after,
    *::before {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
        overflow: hidden;
        /* we don't want the pseudo-elements sticking out */
    }

    section {
        position: relative;
        padding: 10em 10%;
        background: red;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .color {
        background: red;
    }

    /*** Individual section styles and separators ***/

    /* Common style for pseudo-elements */
    section::before,
    section::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        pointer-events: none;
    }


    /* Double Diagonal line */

    .ss-style-doublediagonal {
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 6em;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .ss-style-doublediagonal::before,
    .ss-style-doublediagonal::after {
        top: 34px;
        left: 39%;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 150%;
        height: 75%;
        background: inherit;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 263px 63px 0;
        transform-origin: 263px 63px 0;
    }

    .ss-style-doublediagonal::before {
        height: 28%;
        background: blue;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-178deg);
        transform: rotate(-178deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 28% 0;
        transform-origin: 28% 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your answer but please see the original demo, and its reaction when scaling up and scaling down the view-port. It needs to be fluid like the original.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c5yy8/2/)

```
*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* we don't want the pseudo-elements sticking out */
}

section {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10em 10%;
    background: yellow;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.color {
    background: yellow;
}

/*** Individual section styles and separators ***/

/* Common style for pseudo-elements */
section::before,
section::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
}


/* Double Diagonal line */

.ss-style-doublediagonal {
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 6em;
    background: red;
}

.ss-style-doublediagonal::before,
.ss-style-doublediagonal::after {
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    transform: rotate(4deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 76% 0;
    transform-origin: 76% 0;
}

.ss-style-doublediagonal::before {
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 105% 0;
    transform-origin: 105% 0;
}
.container {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
}
```

I guess that solves it.......

Comment: Hi Danny, Thanks for your answer but please see the original demo, and its reaction when scaling up and scaling down the view-port. It needs to be fluid like the original.

Comment: I guess u can write a media query for that

Comment: Actually the scaling is working perfectly for me...... Which browser are you trying out???

Comment: i am using firefox, yes you could write a media query but there is a better solution, see Niet the Dark Absol's answer that i accepted.